# How to get lowest audio latency response to touch event?

Tags: audiokit

I'm building a rhythm game and trying to provide extremely low latency audio response to the user using AudioKit.

I'm new to AudioKit, following the Hello world example, I built a very simple test app using AKOscillator:

```swift
...
let oscillator = AKOscillator()
...
AudioKit.output = oscilator
oscillator.frequency = 880
AKSettings.bufferLength = .shortest
AKSettings.ioBufferDuration = 0.002
AudioKit.start()

... // On Touch event ///
oscillator.start()
... // 20 ms later ///
oscillator.stop()
```

I measured the latency between touch event and the first sound coming out, it's around 100ms, which is way to slow for us...

Few possibilities I could think:

1. 100 ms is hitting the hardware limit of the audio output delay
2. some more magic settings can fix this
3. oscillator.start() has some delay, to achieve lowest latency I should use something else
4. something wrong with the other parts of the code (touch handling etc.)

Since I have now experience on AudioKit (nor iOS audio system...), any piece of information will be really appreciated!